# Integrating Spring Boot with OpenAM(ForgeRock)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, openam, forgerock

I am new to spring security but the scenario I am trying to achieve is to provide basic authentication/authorization(security). The user story requires integration of ForgeRock OpenAM(mandatory) for security. **Scenario:** I have a spring boot microservice which exposes APIs to allow a UI to connect to a server. How can I include OpenAM within spring boot REST service so that I can provide basic security? What all do I require to achieve the same?

Comment: Are you using any kind of API gateway?

Comment: Yes, I might use an API gateway which would make rest calls to the OpenAM. Any idea of the uri's exposed by OpenAM for authentication and authorization?

Answer (score 0):

You can use OAuth2 or OIDC to integrate your REST-Service with OpenAM.

For information on OAuth2 and REST look at this e.g.: https://content.pivotal.io/blog/securing-restful-web-services-with-oauth2

For information on using OAuth2 with OpenAM look here: https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/am/5.5/oauth2-guide/
Same for OIDC with OpenAM: https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/am/5.5/oidc1-guide/

Hope I could help you :)